# Trying to bind GridView from Linq, not sure how to extract data I need

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, gridview

So I have a DataSet I'm treating as an IEnumerable, and then applying a LINQ expression which gathers modulo groups into a var g. Here is the code-behind...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinqSamples samples = new LinqSamples(gvNumbers, this.Page);
        samples.DataSetLinq40();
    }

    private class LinqSamples
    {
        private DataSet testDS;
        private GridView _gv;
        private Page _pg;

        public LinqSamples(GridView gv, Page pg)
        {
            testDS = TestHelper.CreateTestDataSet(pg);
            _gv = gv;
            _pg = pg;
        }

        public void DataSetLinq40()
        {
            var numbers = testDS.Tables["Numbers"].AsEnumerable();

            var numberGroups = from n in numbers
                               group n by n.Field<int>("number") % 5 into g
                               select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

            _gv.DataSource = numberGroups;
            _gv.DataBind();
        }
    }

        internal static DataSet CreateTestDataSet(Page pg)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            // Customers Table
            ds.Tables.Add(CreateNumbersTable());

            ds.AcceptChanges();
            return ds;
        }

        private static DataTable CreateNumbersTable()
        {
            int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Numbers");
            table.Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));

            foreach (int n in numbers)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(new object[] { n });
            }
            return table;
        }
```

...and the .aspx page...

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvNumbers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Group" DataField="Remainder" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Number" DataField="Numbers" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

What I want is for one column in the GridView to have the modulo group, say for example 0, and the other column to have all the numbers in that group, comma delimited, so for 0 that would be, "0, 5", for 1 that would be "1, 6", for 2 "2, 7", etc. How can I do this with the linq result I already have, which contains the data?

When I run the page the second column show that g is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Data.DataRow]`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably assinging query to datasource instead of collection, use .ToList()

```
_gv.DataSource = justNums.ToList();
_gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: No sorry, I made an edit after that. It *must* be that I do something to the 'Numbers = g' clause in the Linq expression to make it a list of strings or something.

Comment: You may use the group functions e.g. you can use g.Count() to get the number of elements in the group.

Comment: what would be the equivalent of 'g.GetAll()'?